# What sort of clothing should I pack for a trip to Geneva in early October

Tags: weather-and-climate, clothing

I am visiting Geneva in this early month of October (08th-14th). I am wondering what to pack that might be favorable for the weather.

Comment: Geneva in Switzerland?

Comment: Search -weather geneva 14 days- and you will get at least 2 sites showing the weather, including temperatures and rain predictions. Most sites allow you to select C or F. I would wear summer clothing with an extra layer which is warm. You might need less or more, depending one what you are used to.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what climate you are used to, but i think a sweater and a moderate jacket will be enough to keep you warm. (Don't forget the rest of the clothes)
[This](https://www.srf.ch/meteo/lokalprognose?id=417339674) link will direct you to the weather site of the swiss radio and television, which is independent and quite good in my opinion. Low will be at 8°C and high at 17°C.

When you want to travel to the mountains, bring warm clothes with you, as it probably will have snow in higher regions from this weekend on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working next to Lake Geneva at the moment.

I'm going to work in the morning with a sweatshirt/jumper. No need for a coat. Though often an umbrella is necessary.

At lunch time it is sometimes warm enough that I'm just wearing a shirt.

Though as a disclaimer I'm from northern Europe. If you're coming from e.g. India your mileage may vary.

Contrary to stereotypes the shores of the lake actually have a pretty warm Mediterranean style climate, it's only once you get to higher altitudes that more stereotypical Swiss cold kicks in.